# How to disable an account after being created 30 days

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, group-policy

Is there any built-in group policy object in windows server 2003 or 2008 for disabling an account or set of accounts in an organizational unit after 30 days since that account was created. If there is no built-in one, how can I establish that group policy object

Answer (score 3):

As shown in the quote below, there is no GPO for this action. 
You could use the **[dsquery](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725702(WS.10%29.aspx)** command to create a script that finds users who have been inactive for 30 days with the **-inactive switch**

> To display the distinguished names of all users in the current domain
>   only whose names end with "Smith" and who have been inactive for three
>   weeks or more, type:
>
> ```
> dsquery user domainroot -name *smith -inactive 3
> ```

[This post](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/f3c72be6-00f7-4b14-a961-b8964940d862/gpo-used-to-disable-staleunused-domain-accounts) on the Microsoft Technet lists the information from above:

> There is no in-built GPO for the same.
>
> Alternately you can use **dsquery** to list users who have not login in
>   the past 30 days and disable the account.
>
> Use the -**inactive** switch
>   http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725702(WS.10).aspx other
>   good methods are using adtidy (free GUI tool)
>   http://www.cjwdev.co.uk/Software/ADTidy/Info.html dsquery user
>   -inactive 4  (which will list accounts inactive for 4 WEEKS) or use http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/oldcmp/index.htm